# How to get long text object change log programmatically?

Tags: abap, audit-trail, sap-data-dictionary

I have a requirement to fetch all changes that were made to a long text object.

From what I know, there is a program called **S_AUT_REP10** where you can see the changes that were made to a long text in ALV but I can't seem to find how to extract this data in my code.

I know that the data is somehow stored in `STXH`, `STXL` and dbtablog for the changes but would really appreciate any help extracting the actual changes that were made to the long text.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the datasource by pressing `Start evaluation` button in the left apper corner of the screen after triggering the report by your parameters.

[image]

It shows where the data comes from, in this case it is the STXH table by certain key

```
<client><obj>*<text_name>*<text_id>*
```

This key will be of great use when you will be fetching the DBTABLOG.

Recreation of the S_AUT_REP10-like query in the ABAP code will look like this

```
DATA: tabname   TYPE aut_t_tabname_range
      logkey    TYPE aut_t_logkey_range
      from_date LIKE sy-datum
      from_time LIKE st-timlo.

  APPEND INITIAL LINE TO tabname
    ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_r_tabname>).
  <ls_r_tabname>-sign   = 'I'.
  <ls_r_tabname>-option = 'CP'.
  <ls_r_tabname>-low    = 'STXH'.
  APPEND INITIAL LINE TO logkey
    ASSIGNING <ls_r_logkey>.
  <ls_r_logkey>-sign   = 'I'.
  <ls_r_logkey>-option = 'CP'.
  <ls_r_logkey>-low    = '800TEXT*ZT_TB_PHSTF-PH110*ST*'.

  from_date = '20211231'.
  from_time = '235959'.

  SELECT SINGLE logdate logtime logid FROM dbtablog     "#EC *
    INTO DATA(ls_dbtablog)
      WHERE
        logdate  =  from_date   AND
        logtime  >= from_time   AND
        tabname  IN tabname  AND
        logkey   IN logkey.
```